# Eclipse C/C++ Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) how to include the semaphore ?

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore

I'm experimenting with threads and synchronization of threads in c, in eclipse(mars) on windows. `#include <semaphore.h>` library is missing. how to install it for this IDE? older solutions doesn't seem to apply..

Comment: [`<semaphore.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/semaphore.h.html) is a POSIX header file, which means it only exist on POSIX system like Linux, BSD and OSX. If you want to use Windows native semaphores I suggest you start reading [about synchronization on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681924%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: If you want to use Linux libs, install [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have no problem in linux environment with this, .. the reason i wanted to use windows is because , i'm new to c and wanted an IDE for c with all the good stuff that an IDE provides, .. gedit and the eclipse for linux doesn't seem to have the functionality... like syntax error check.. highlight occurrence..

Comment: Eclipse should be pretty complete, what is it you miss? As for the problem, that's what I'm saying, the `<semaphore.h>` header exist on Linux but not on Windows. If you want to use native threading primitives then you need to learn about them, which is what my [MSDN (MicroSoft Developer Network)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx) link was for.For Windows specific things, MSDN is the site you should default to.

Comment: got it. using eclipse in linux now, it is working. thanx for help.